# Why can't I push an object into an instance array?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to implement the Observer Pattern in Ruby from scratch, but an error that I can't understand stopped me while programming.

I have created a method to add some objects into an instance Array, but when I call this method, the interpreter returns me an error that says:

> undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass
>   Did you mean?  puts
>   (repl):15:in`addObserver'
>   (repl):36:in `'

I have defined the array, so do you know why I receive this error?

(I receive this error when I call: matchOne.addObserver(playerOne))

Here is the complete code:

```
class Match

 attr_accessor :observers, :result

 @observers = Array.new
 @result = 0

 def notifyAll
   @observers.each do |observer|
   observer.update(self)
   end
 end

 def addObserver(observer)
   @observers.push(observer)
 end

 def increaseResult
   @result += 1 
   notifyAll
 end

end

class Player

 def update(match)
   puts "The result is #{match.result}"
 end

end

playerOne = Player.new 
matchOne = Match.new 

matchOne.addObserver(playerOne)
```

I thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@observers = Array.new
@result = 0
```

Should be

```
def initialize
  @observers = Array.new
  @result = 0
end
```

Comment: Is it necessary that these two variables are instantiated inside a method?

Comment: That code is executed but it's not in the same scope of the code in the others methods. So if you want to access those variable in `addObserver` etc yes, you should put it in the initialize method.

Comment: Thank you, now I have understand it :)

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)